# Android - Firebase - Do I need to remove EVERY single listener?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, firebase, firebase-storage

I did a reasonable amount of research and can not find the answer I need.

**What I DO know:** When I attach a ValueEventListener to a database reference, I know I need to remove it later (finding that out the hard way now with some massive memory leakage.

**What I DON'T know:** Do I also need to detach all other listeners? *(This is to include Firebase Database, Storage, and Auth, the three APIs I am using)*

Example:

```
UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(uploadFile);

uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    //@Override code here
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TakeSnapshot>() {
    //@Override code here
}).addOnProgressListner(new OnProgressListner<UploadTask.TakeSnapshot>() {
    //@Override code here
};
```

I think that's enough to show you the point of what I mean. This is how my actual code is currently structured.

**Questions:**

1. Do I need to remove all of those listeners just in case the activity
   is terminated (system decision, phone dies, whatever) before that
   callback happens?
2. Can I bundle them up somehow and terminate them all three at once
   because I have like 30 of these in my code and really don't feel
   like restructuring all of it in order to assign all these listeners
   to variables JUST so I can pass them into the
   "removeBlahBlahBlahListener(listenerVariable)" over and over.
3. Slightly off topic, but, I am too lazy to move all my code from
   onCreate to onStart... is is bad practice for me to remove all these
   listeners, finish things up, call finish() (or whatever it is that
   kills off an activity, although I guess this is not guaranteed) and just recreate the activity from scratch?
   It's a small simple app so the overhead of re-creating the activity
   is no biggie. Just curious what is "right".

I imagine this is just a result of poor planning and lack of knowledge (I only program for fun, not for a job unfortunately) so if I have to take the hard route I guess it's a learning experience, right?

Comment: I'm confused. The example code you show is a progress listener for Firebase Storage. But your text is clearly about the database. Which one are you having problems with?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion Frank. I could have been more clear. I am using both APIs (DB and Storage) from Firebase and have listeners in both. My question really was meant to apply to both I suppose. I guess Firebase listeners in general and when they do and do not need detached/removed. For instance, are there some FB listeners that take care of themselves when the activity is moved out of view or will every single listener (DB and Storage) continue to listen even after onPause/Stop/Destroy etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Auto unregistering listeners when an activity stops is a feature on the class "Task" in android and its derived classes (StorageTask).

This means you can do something like this:

```
UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(uploadFile);

uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(thisActivity, new OnFailureListener() {
//@Override code here
}).addOnSuccessListener(thisActivity, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
//@Override code here
}).addOnProgressListner(thisActivity, new OnProgressListner<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
//@Override code here
};
```

You can also do this with Task objects returned from the realtime Database such as setValue as in:

```
databaseReference.setValue("newValue").addOnSuccessListener(thisActivity, ...)
```

So to answer your questions directly:

1. Use the activity scoped version to automatically unregister the listeners on activity stop.  Note that for storage, you can query running operations when your activity starts using StorageReference.getActiveUploadTasks and StorageReference.getActiveDownloadTasks and re-subscribe.
2. You shouldn't need to unsubscribe manually if using scoped listeners.  I do not know of a way to batch unsubscribe to non-task based listeners.
3. Well I'm not sure how you can guarantee that the OS will always kill your task instead of stopping/starting it again -- and how your finish code will be guaranteed to run.  I would advise you move the code to onStart

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. Excellent answer and exactly the information I was looking for. So where you put "thisActivity" in the storage examples, is that the same as if I put "this" or does "this" describe something other than the activity? I see I can do "this.getCallingActivity" and a few other things. Can you tell me what the proper way to reference the activity so I don't end up referencing something else? Also, I will take your advice and move some of my onCreate() logic to the onStart(). It should have been there to begin with. Learning the lesson the hard way! ;)

Comment: usually "this" refers to the activity while inside code of an activity.  It may not, however, if you are inside a nested class or callback routine.  If you find yourself there, you can specifically reference the activity by qualifying "this" with a type  -- as in "MainActivity.this"

Comment: that last comment just put the icing on the cake. memory leak solved :)

Comment: @BenjaminWulfe I cant seem to do the same with `addValueEventListener`. Any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe this is only a feature of Tasks.

Comment: is there a way to unregister listeners in fragments  ?